# Flutter update widget while dragging another one

Tags: flutter, draggable

I am new to Flutter and I'm trying to build an app with two draggable circles with a line going from one circles to the other

[image: gif of the application]

I managed to do that but the line does not follow the circles during the drag dues to the circle position being updated only after the drag ends.

I would like to have my line that follows my circle during the drag and I don't know how to do that.
Something like that:

[image]

Here is a Github containing my code example : [flutter_drag_example](https://github.com/sup3rgalou/flutter_drag_example)

I tried using the onDragUpdate to set the state with the circle position during the drag but this doesn't work (probably because setting state cause the widget to rebuild idk)

Answer (score 0):

**I'm trying to slove your problem.
Here is example code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(DraggableCirclesApp());
}

class DraggableCirclesApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Draggable Circles',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: DraggableCirclesScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class DraggableCirclesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DraggableCirclesScreenState createState() => _DraggableCirclesScreenState();
}

class _DraggableCirclesScreenState extends State<DraggableCirclesScreen> {
  Offset circleOnePosition = Offset(50, 200);
  Offset circleTwoPosition = Offset(250, 200);
  double circleRadius = 50;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Draggable Circles'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          CustomPaint(
            size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
            painter: ShapesPainter(circleOnePosition, circleTwoPosition, circleRadius),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: circleOnePosition.dx - circleRadius,
            top: circleOnePosition.dy - circleRadius,
            child: Draggable(
              feedback: Container(
                width: circleRadius * 2,
                height: circleRadius * 2,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
                ),
              ),
              child: Container(
                width: circleRadius * 2,
                height: circleRadius * 2,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              onDraggableCanceled: (_, __) {},
              onDragEnd: (details) {
                setState(() {
                  circleOnePosition = details.offset;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: circleTwoPosition.dx - circleRadius,
            top: circleTwoPosition.dy - circleRadius,
            child: Draggable(
              feedback: Container(
                width: circleRadius * 2,
                height: circleRadius * 2,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
                ),
              ),
              child: Container(
                width: circleRadius * 2,
                height: circleRadius * 2,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              onDraggableCanceled: (_, __) {},
              onDragEnd: (details) {
                setState(() {
                  circleTwoPosition = details.offset;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ShapesPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Offset circleOnePosition;
  final Offset circleTwoPosition;
  final double circleRadius;

  ShapesPainter(this.circleOnePosition, this.circleTwoPosition, this.circleRadius);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0;

    canvas.drawLine(circleOnePosition, circleTwoPosition, paint);

    canvas.drawCircle(circleOnePosition, circleRadius, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(circleTwoPosition, circleRadius, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you achieve the same point than me. In your example (and in mine too) the line position update when the drag end. I want it to update during the drag so that it follows the dragged point

Comment: No both example are different

Comment: Yes it is different because you used a different approach than me to draw the circles and the line. But it does not do what I asked... Your line doesn't move during the drag. I want it to move during the drag and to follow the dragged circle while its dragged. I edited the question adding a gif of what I want to achieve